# openserver не запускается вместе с любой версией mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, openserver

Так же запускается только с nginx (но так же только без Mysql)

Не запускается(1) :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускается(2) :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не запускается :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже 3 раза его переустановил и он просто не хочет работать, а если и вдруг включается сам по себе очень редко, выдает 502 error на всех страницах,
Я переустанавливал его уже 3 раза ставил разные версии и 5.4.0 Но везде одно и тоже,
Я думаю это изза выключения света послдений раз (возмоджно)
Неужели единсвенный выход это переустановка винды? Я уже перепробовал все вариации apache + php
Очень грустно, и базу главное не восставноить ;(
Cпасибо за ответы!!!

Comment: Ну логи смотрите. А то "не работает, там что-то магия какая-то, свет вырубили, и вот теперь у базы способности превращаться в черную дыру")))

Comment: А где можно логи sql смотреть? ато openserver логи говорят только что не удалось запустить .... ;(

Comment: `userdata/logs/` - mysql и nginx смотреть, 502 точно попадает в nginx